# Правильные ударения "на реку", "на доску"

Tags: фонетика

Всегда считала, что правильно говорить "на рЕку", "на дОску". Но недавно где-то попалась информация, что тут ударение плавающее, и можно говорить и "на доскУ", "на рекУ". Правда ли это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правда. См. последние издания Лопатина или Кузнецова (хотя Кузнецов в этом вопросе вторичен).

Answer (score 1):

Ох уж мне эти Фурсенковские нововведения... Только язык засоряют. Скоро и ударения в "ложить" обсуждать начнут. "На рЕку", но "на рекЕ".

Comment: Тимур, вы заблуждаетесь. Во-первых, названные мною словари – действительно авторитетные и заслуживающие доверия издания, которые к тому же не имеют ровно никакого отношения к фигуре одиозного министра (вы, вероятно, путаете их с «узаконенными» словарями Букчиной, Резниченко и др.?). Во-вторых, колебания в ударении здесь целиком соответствуют языковой логике (схожий случай наблюдаем, к примеру, в формах косвенных падежей некоторых существительных 2-го школьного склонения: *у мостА/у мОста*).

Comment: Показательно, что, сетуя на «нововведения», вы в качестве нормы приводите как раз сравнительно молодой вариант *на рЕку,* забывая о «старшем» варианте *нА реку* (который также является нормой). Как всегда, ничего личного. :) P.S.: любопытно, мне одному ограничения на длину комментариев кажутся *чуточку чересчур* строгими?..

Comment: Про "нА реку" не имею ничего против - сам так говорю. А вот "у мОста" вряд ли у меня когда вырвется...  
Про длину комментариев согласен, "маловато будет" :)

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не правда. 
Правильно - нА реку  и на дОску.  (Зарава)

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0
http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0

В первом сочетании ударение **всегда** на предлоге, во втором - ударение "на доскУ" возможно в устоявшихся выражениях.

Без предлога возможно рЕку и рекУ, но только дОску. 
*Лопатин допускает и доскУ (без предлога), но я бы не рекомендовал пока следовать этому варианту до закрепления его в собственно орфоэпических словарях.*

Answer (score 0):

Правильно-на рЕку и на дОску!Проверочное слово рЕки,дОски!

Comment: Вы ударения отметили таким образом или просто сомнительную букву?