# Вдогонку о досках

Tags: фонетика

Где-то мне попадалась информация, что допустимо ударение не только "на дОску", "на рЕку", но и "на доскУ", "на рекУ". Это правда?
И снова спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было уже: [Правильные ударения "на реку", "на доску"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83)

Лопатин: http://www.dict.t-mm.ru/all/reka.html